# Codedom Dynamic code generation detected as a virus

Tags: c#, codedom, virus

i cant seem to get this to not be detected as a virus
I use this code to generate a c# executable from a String 'Source'
(Source is an empty project: using system;, namespace, main. Thats it)

```
var results = CompileCsharpSource(new[] { Source }, txtFile.Text); 
        if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("No Errors - Successfully built");
        else
        {
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                MessageBox.Show(error.ErrorText);
        }
    }
    private static CompilerResults CompileCsharpSource(string[] sources, string output, params string[] references)
    {
        //build function
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(references, output);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            return provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sources);
    }
```

The generated executable is saved where the user chooses and has 2KB smaller filesize than the exact same empty project in Visual Studio and Avira detects it as a virus but doesnt detect the VS project as one.

Why does it have a different filesize and why is it detected as a virus by Avira?
How to stop it being detected as one, also.

Note: the lack of references where it is asked for, even with them, i get the same result

Avira says its 'Dropper', it seems to say this a lot for my applications :P I just dont understand it when codeDom is building a blank application :(

Comment: Does it tell what is the name of the virus it thinks it is?

Comment: It sounds more like you have some virus that your AV is not detecting and infecting stuff...

Comment: have you found a fix?